# Angular error on npm run front : Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, angular

Working on Angular 11 project, during npm run front I am facing below error.

The error is : xxvvyz front: `node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --configuration es5 --proxy- config proxy.config.json`

In package.json file I already have this

```
"front": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --configuration es5 --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
"build:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=4800 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"
```

node version: v16.13.2 ,  npm version: 6.14.8 and angular version: 11.2.14.
Other developers in my team has same versions. They are not facing this issue. I checked few solutions, most of them are saying, downgrading the node version helps to resolve the issue but I can't change the version of node as other developers are using this and I would need admin rights for that.

here is the image of whole error in case I am missing something.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z0O8.png)

Installed Ram: 16.0 GB (15.4 GB usable)

Answer (score 0):

Maximum call stack exceeded usually happens due to an infinite loop. I would suggest you to add a debugger and check the execution line by line to know where the issue lies.